# How to perform function call of the main process in the main process of the electron?

Tags: electron

I'm creating an application using electron and I'm in a situation where I created a tray menu, and by clicking it I would like to perform an already implemented action that I already call from the process renderer, but I tried and did not succeed reusing this function by calling from of the main process.

TRAY In the main process:

```
const traytemplate = [{
   'label': 'About',
   click: () => {
        / * make call here * /
   }
}
]
```

FUNCTION OF OPENING THE WINDOW ON

```
ipcMain.on ('open-over', () => {
      / * open the window over here * /
})
```

I need to call the '' open-over '' from the main process. Can someone help me?

I would like to know how to perform the call of the main process function from it (main process), since I already use this function calling from the renderer process

*** Before it is suggested, my tray can not be created in the renderer and be worked there.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about naming the handler function?

```
const openWindow = () => {
  // open the window
}

ipcMain.on('open-hover', openWindow)

const traytemplate = [{
  'label': 'About',
  click: () => {
    openWindow()
  }
}]
```